# Is it possible to display an element which is outside an element that has overflow: scroll?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have

```
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="abs"></div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top:100px;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid turquoise;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.abs{
    position: absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:-50px;
    left:0;
    border:1px solid orange;
}
```

Right now .abs and .fixed has the same parent and I use javascript to position it above the fixed element, but I wonder if there is an other way.

So is it possible somehow to make .abs visible? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fujmw79t/)

Comment: `overflow:hidden` and `overflow:scroll` behave similarly. In a sense, `scroll` works the same as `hidden` and provides a scrollbar to view the entire content. So, with your current markup I don't see how this could be done.

Answer (score 2):

I did not really get the idea why you have to do that.

BTW. You should have a fixed container. HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed"></div>
    <div class="abs"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid turquoise;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.abs{
    position: absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:-30px;
    left:0;
    border:1px solid orange;
}
.container {
 position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    top: 40px; left: 40px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fujmw79t/3/

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `overflow:scroll;` on `.fixed`:

```css
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top:100px;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid turquoise;
}
.abs{
    position: absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:-53px;
    left:-1px;
    border:1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="abs"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have content in .fixed that can be more, than 100%, so I must have the overfow scroll property